# How to trim out a sub string value

Tags: javascript

I am having a time string like this **9:00:10 AM** and **12:10:20 PM**.

So I want to remove the seconds value from the above string, so the above should look like this
**9:00 AM**, **12:10 PM**

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a regular expression. For example

```js
const s = '9:00:10 AM'
const t = '12:10:20 AM'

console.log(s.replace(/:\d{1,2}[ ]{1}/, ' ')) // 9:00 AM
console.log(t.replace(/:\d{1,2}[ ]{1}/, ' ')) // 12:10 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use regular expressions and you need full control of the strict format and yet have the chance to easily craft a different output, here I show how to parse the datetime parts inside the string and how to put them back together in a different template.

```js
const inputs = ['9:00:10 AM', '12:10:20 PM', '12:01:01 PM'];

inputs.forEach(input => console.log(transform(input)) );

function transform(input){
  var re = /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s(AM|PM)$/img; 
  var match = re.exec(input);
  if (match != null) {
      const hours = match[1];
      const minutes = match[2];
      const seconds = match[3];
      const ampm = match[4];
      
      return `${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
  }
  else{
    return input;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your times are in an array, you can alternatively use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
    const times = ['9:00:10 AM', '12:10:20 AM']

    console.log(
    times.map(x=> x.replace(/\:\d{2} /,' '))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

With the replaceAll() method, you can use an empty String to remove a substring from a string. Syntax: string. replace(No.

Comment: your answer seems truncated. Can you edit it and complete it?